# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.name() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Tags: java, groovy

I am new to this groovy script, as i have requirement to update the java 1.7 to java8 for my project,after upgrading the version both java & groovy then facing issue with the groovy syntax.
In java 7 it worked without any issues,but in java 8 facing below error .

The below error is occruing while i am trying to find specific tag element as below :

```
def tradeString = msg."**".find{it.name() == "m__tradeString"}
```

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.name() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: take(int), take(int), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), dump()
```

Note : in some places name() method is working but other places facing this error

please help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the message I see, that `it` in the closure is String. So, try `.find{it == "m__tradeString"}`.

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka
Thanks for your time, I have tried it but it return null though tag is available in the msg. i tried below two possibilities  node return that tag node, but node1 retrun null.

 def node = msg."**".find { it.'m__tradeString'.text())                                                                               

def node1 = msg."**".find { it == 'm__tradeString'}                                                                           

Atleast it is working for node but i want to pass the tagname dyanmically is there any 
syntax to concat the dynamic value

Comment: sorry I cannot understand what type of objects you are interacting with, so I'm just guessing, based on the syntax I see. Another try I suggest `def tradeString = msg."**".find{it.getName() == "m__tradeString"}` or  `def tradeString = msg."**".find{it.name == "m__tradeString"}`.

Comment: What does `msg."**"` evaluate to?

Comment: `println(msg.class)`,  `println((msg."**").class)` could make it more clear

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka `msg.class` may not help.  For example, if `msg` is a `Map` and the `Map` does not have a key with the value `'class'`, then `msg.class` will evaluate to `null`.  Know what `msg."**"`is will be more valuable.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown -
Here is the code snipet :
Type of Message :
org.springframework.integration -public interface Message<T> 
Message message;
def payload = message.payload.newObjectXML
XmlParser parser = new XmlParser();
Node msg = parser.parseText(payload)

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka
I tried the change which you have suggested : 
def nodelement = msg."**".find { it.getName() == "m__tradeString" }
Error :
Exception in execute=No signature of method: groovy.util.Node.getName() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: name(), getAt(groovy.namespace.QName), getAt(groovy.xml.QName), getAt(java.lang.String), getClass(), get(java.lang.String)

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka
I have tried the below two statements :  both printed "[]"
println(msg.class) : return [] 
println((msg."**").class) :return []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion in comments..

For now I see you iterating through the collection with `groovy.util.Node` objects, and calling `it.name()` seems valid for them.

But from the initial error message in your question I saw the String object too. So you might have at least 2 different types (String and Node). And you have to handle this.

```
def tradeString = msg."**".find{
    String expected = 'm__tradeString'
    String actual = it instanceof groovy.util.Node ? it.name() : it
    actual == expected
}
```

This code can be shortened of course.

And for such cases I suggest to look throw the initial collection in debugger, or print each object type `.getClass()` and `.toString()`. So It'll become more clear.

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.name() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Means that method `name()` was invoked on `java.lang.String`, but this class doesn't have such method.

---

Less code version:

```
// this method can be reused
static String extractNodeName(node) {
    node instanceof groovy.util.Node ? node.name() : node
}

def tradeString = msg."**".find{ extractNodeName(it) =='m__tradeString' }
```

Comment: The above solution worked, thank you so much.

Comment: Great! You are welcome.

Comment: - suggested solution syntax is looks like big ,can we have short syntax ? the reason for this question is am using this syntax almost 100+ places in the code .

Comment: @Jami, I'll add also the shorter version..

Comment: @ Max Daroshchanka. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me when I used a variable with the same name as a method.
Example:
A function with sshCommand String parameter, in which I called:
`sshCommand remote: remote, command: fullCommand`

(fullCommand was sshCommand  with some flags I added).
So I had a string, and after that used the method, that was not a string, and this gave the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when I called a variable like a method.

I did

```
isSearchPage()
```

I should do:

```
isSearchPage
```